# NSMutableArray Multidimensional overwriting itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, arrays, multidimensional-array

i'm trying to retrieve data from an XML document and store it in a multidimensional `NSMutableArray`. The problem is that it seems to be overwriting itself?

i've declared the arrays cols and rows in the ViewDidLoad method. like this:

```
rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
cols = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

The XML parse method is:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
    didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
    qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{  
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"song"]) {

        title = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"title"];
        songId = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"id"];
        singer = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"author"];
        theDuration = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"duration"];
        theLink = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"link"];

        [cols addObject: title];
        [cols addObject: songId];
        [cols addObject: singer];
        [cols addObject: theDuration];
        [cols addObject: theLink];

        [rows addObject: cols];   
    }
}
```

This is my XML doc. As you can see the first 2 songs id are 0 and the next to 1 and next 2 is 2. The problem is here that the Array seems to put 0 in all of the 6 don objects as the id.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Lists>
<playlist title="Quo Vadis" id="0"/>
    <song title="One Perfect Day" link="m01MYOpbdIk" duration="3:15" author="Rune RK" id="0" />
    <song title="two Perfect Day" link="m01MYOpbdIk" duration="3:15" author="Rune RK" id="0" />

<playlist title="Lord of the Rings" id="1"/>
    <song title="three Perfect Day" link="m01MYOpbdIk" duration="3:15" author="Rune RK" id="1" />
    <song title="fourth Perfect Day" link="m01MYOpbdIk" duration="3:15" author="Rune RK" id="1" />
<playlist title="Face" id="2"/>
    <song title="five Perfect Day" link="m01MYOpbdIk" duration="3:15" author="Rune RK" id="2" />
    <song title="six Perfect Day" link="m01MYOpbdIk" duration="3:15" author="Rune RK" id="2" />
</Lists>
```

i'm using this to print it:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[rows objectAtIndex:3] objectAtIndex:1 ]);
```

Comment: can you show the result?

Comment: Can you show how you declared rows and cols

Comment: Note that `objectForKey:` is the dedicated method to retrieve a value from a dictionary. `valueForKey:` is used if you need some "Key-Value Coding" magic.

Comment: Your log statement could be shorter `NSLog(@"%@", rows[3][1])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be reusing the same `cols` instance for every row. You can't do that. You need to create a new `cols` instance for each row:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"song"]) {
        title = attributeDict[@"title"];
        songId = attributeDict[@"id"];
        singer = attributeDict[@"author"];
        theDuration = attributeDict[@"duration"];
        theLink = attributeDict[@"link"];

        NSArray *cols = @[ title, songId, singer, theDuration, theLink ];

        [rows addObject: cols];
    }
}
```

Remove your `cols` ivar. It's not needed with this update.

Also, don't use `valueForKey:` with the dictionary unless you really mean to be using KVC. Use `objectForKey:` or as I did here, the new modern syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a spin-off of [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy)'s (great) answer. When you use a literal array -- e.g. `@[thing1, thing2]` -- you'll be in trouble if any of the things is `nil`. One way to bulletproof this would be to check for this before you create the array. The C trinary operator is a good way to do this:

```
thing1 = dict[@"key"] ? dict[@"key"] : @"";
```

Which sets `thing1` to `dict[@"key"]` if it is non-`nil`, and an empty string if it's `nil`. In shorthand (and more efficient):

```
thing1 = dict[@"key"] ?: @"";
```

Using this in your code, and assuming those variables are all strings:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
    didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
    qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs
{  
   // presumably other code ...
   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"song"]) {
        title = attrs[@"title"] :? @"";
        songId = attrs[@"id"] :? @"";
        singer = attrs[@"author"] :? @"";
        theDuration = attrs[@"duration"] :? @"";
        theLink = attrs[@"link"] :? @"";

        [rows addObject:@[ title, songId, singer, theDuration, theLink ]];
    }
}
```

Because I find it cleaner, I also skip adding the local variable `cols`, and add the literal array directly.